# "Heatbars" for visualizing consecutive missing data days?

Tags: r, ggplot2, time-series

I am trying to visualize large chunks of consecutive missing data side-by-side on ranges of 3, 5 and 10 years sampled daily. Hopefully using ggplot2 since I already have some aesthetics functions done.

I imagined this would come from a barplot or maybe some heatmap variation, but I am not too sure how to use them with time-series data.

I chose a black/white list of bars because I think it is easier to observe where (1) lies large chunks of missing data and (2) if they are occurring on different moments in time (which would be important to choose which stations to use, etc), while being (3) relatively easy to observe many bars which would not be true to the more conventional line plots for time-series.

This is a draft of what I had in mind. [image: draft example]

Here is some example data for 5 stations (in practice this could be up to over 80):

```
#Data from 5 different stations sampled daily. 
df <- cbind(seq(as.Date(("2010/01/01")),by="day",length.out=365*5),data.frame(matrix(rnorm(365*5*5),365*5,5)))
colnames(df) <- c("timestamp","st1","st2","st3","st4","st5")
#Add varying ranges of missing consecutive amount of days to observe result on visualization.
df[1:50,"st1"] <- NA # 50 
df[51:200,"st2"] <- NA # 150 
df[1:400,"st3"] <- NA # 400
df[501:1300,"st5"] <- NA # 800
```

Answer (score 5):

Here's a rough stab at it...Alter the scales and theme elements to your liking...

```
library(ggplot2)
library(scales)
library(reshape2)
melt(df, id.vars = "timestamp") -> k
k$value <- ifelse(is.na(k$value), "NA", "Not NA")

ggplot(data = k) + 
    geom_point(aes(x = timestamp, y = variable, fill = value, colour = value), shape =22) +
    scale_x_date() +
    theme_bw()
```

[image]